# Have I over oiled the wok when seasoning

Tags: seasoning-pans, wok

I've recently purchased my first wok and attempted to season it following guides on Youtube.

It has turned a nice dark colour however it is slightly sticky to the touch and has some raised surfaces that are likely excess oil.

Does this mean I have seasoned it wrong or will it be okay to use as it is?  If I've done something wrong how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you used too much oil and too little heat. What guide did you follow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used too much oil, or you haven't wiped enough off before heating the pan, the end result is the same.

The best thing to do would be to remove the oil and try again, making sure that you have wiped the wok properly. 
Also, 1) make sure the wok is a bit warm before wiping it with oil (At least if it is cast iron) as this helps it absorb the oil properly; 2) When "baking" the wok in your oven, put it in upside down to prevent the oil "pooling" (And put something in the bottom of your oven to catch any oil that might drip.

Good luck.